# Highcharts yaxis price line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to setup in Highcharts the ability to show show the current yaxis value and have it highlighted.

Below is an example, in this charts which is Highcharts, you'll see the horizontal black line with the current value selected with the black label.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thank you!

[image: example]

Comment: Does it need to show what the point's yValue is or any value along the yAxis?

Comment: Yeah, basically it shows the yValue in the black label.  Essentially the chart is a "live" chart and that label and black line changes with each update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- use `plotLines` to add one with value of last point. Of course when new point is added, remove previous `plotLine` and add new one with new value.
- use plugin for it: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/28/Current%20Price%20Indicator

There is of course another solution - use renderer to render line with label, but it's more complicated ;)